# In the Starter Set, how can PCs learn the password?

Tags: dnd-5e, lost-mine-of-phandelver

In the D&D 5th starter set scenario(Lost mine of Phandelver), there's a part where players can repel skeletons by saying a password (p.22). However, I cannot find where & how players learn this password in the scenario. Could you enlighten me here please?

**Spoiler Alert !! The following is the script from the scenario book.**

> The three skeletons are animated and attack any creature that comes within 10 feet of the door leading to area 5 or the door leading to area 6, unless that creature is wearing the scarlet cloak of the Redbrands or speaks the password "Illefarn" (the name of an ancient elven nation, which once spread across much of the Sword Coast)

Comment: Shoooot I've been searching hard to find if someone has asked the same question but couldn't find one... but here it is. :(

Comment: That's alright--that means this post can serve as a signpost for future users in your position, and they won't have as hard a time finding good answers. Thank you for your service!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### They'd have to learn it from a Redbrand.

Two ways that can happen: wittingly or unwittingly.

On p.20 is a sidebar describing what a generic Redbrand might know and share if questioned. It's no stretch to allow a particularly good line of questioning, or a particularly persuasive questioner, to gain the password as well. The presence of skeletons guarding the crypts is already contemplated as a topic of conversation, after all.

Or a PC could overhear a Redbrand using it. It's an unlikelier scenario (IMO), but there is a *potion of invisibility* in play....

Comment: I don't think Glasstaff have ever told the password to ruffians. But the important part is - PCs don't *have to* learn the password. They probably will fight the skeletons or use the brands.

Comment: My PCs ended up not even knowing the Skeletons were there, since they found and donned the Redbrand cloaks for an entirely different purpose.